# string and variable in to another variable php

Tags: php, string, variables

i have a variable , and i want mix variable and a string . 
eg :

```
$body   = 'Dear customer'.$fname.$textmsg.$footer.$website ;
```

but this format does not work . out put is :

```
Dear customer Mary0
```

help with this string please.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Have you checked the value of the variables?

Comment: From the looks of `$footer` and `$website`, seems like the OP wants  it as pre-formatted template complete with line breaks, including a footer and a link to a web site.

Comment: Show us your full source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you do not have your other variables pre-defined or there is something else breaking your code, which is not posted in its entirety.

Here is a little something I put together as an example (tested)

### PHP

```
<?php
$fname = "Mary";
$textmsg = "Thank you for dropping by my Web site.";
$footer = "This is a footer that will show at 10px from the bottom with the help of CSS.";
$website = "http://www.example.com";
$body = 'Dear (customer) '.$fname . "<br>" .$textmsg . "<div align='center' id='footer'>" . $footer . "</div>" . "<div id='website'>$fname, " . "<a href='" .$website . "'>click here to visit my Web site.</a>" . "</div>";
echo $body;
?>
```

### CSS

```
<style>
body {
margin:10px 0px; padding:0px;
text-align:center;
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Which will produce (with some personalization):

**(centered on top)**
Dear (customer) Mary
Thank you for dropping by my Web site.
Mary, [click here to visit my Web site](http://www.example.com/).

**(10 pixels from the bottom)**
This is a footer that will show at 10px from the bottom with the help of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Is because other variables are empty.
You have two ways to concatenate a string.

First:

```
$body = 'Dear customer'.$fname.$textmsg.$footer.$website;
```

Second:

```
$body   = "Dear customer $fname$textmsg$footer$website";
```